# 50% udp packets lost

Tags: networking, udp

I am sending/receiving very short UDP packets between a computer (C#) and a microcontroller (C++). Independently of the speed, I am losing around 50% of my UDP packets, sometimes more, sometimes less.

In c# I am using a UDPClient sending to a IPEndPoint (synchronous) and receiving asynchronously.

My buffers are big enough and I see that the losses are produced in the computer both sending and receiving (the micro send as many packets as it receives). I am trying to send/receive around 60 packets per second, but I can adjust that and even an 10 packets per second I have losses. For example, I sent 20 packets per second, the micro receives and sends 15, and my computer receives 10 packets per second.

We are talking about a local wired ethernet connection of 1 gigabit, very short (10ft maybe). I am sending unicast packets, although in the network I also have a multicast video (12 Mbps). The biggest packet is about 120 bytes, most of them around 30-40 bytes

Any advice about how to debug the problem or what can cause it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some things to consider:

- Is this a wired connection or a wireless connection? Fifty percent UDP packet loss would of course be more common in the wireless case, though only over a poor link.
- Assuming it is a wireless connection, is the signal strength reasonably high on both devices? You can check this with various utilities, such as `iwconfig` on *nix.
- What is the actual bitrate of the connection? You mention that you are transmitting at various rates, but I assume this refers to how often you are sending packets, rather than the actual bitrate of the link. The faster the bitrate, the higher the expected packet loss. I believe this is a direct result of antenna physics, that data can be transmitted at higher powers if it is transmitted at lower bitrates.
- Are these packets being unicast or broadcast? Broadcasting packets will result in higher packet loss rates. This is due to the lack of a retry mechanism in the lower layers of the networking stack in the broadcast case.
- Though you said your packets are small, another factor affecting UDP packet loss is the size of the packets. This one is rather intuitive: the larger a packet is, the less likely it will be received intact.

Hopefully these considerations will at least get you started in the direction of an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just edited the question adding that extra info.

Comment: @chourizo I am having problems with multicast/udp broadcast packets, I too am experiencing losses +60%, I will report back with any help/information regarding this issue that might be of use. In the mean time, I will be sending duplicate packets i.e. send each packet 2 times incase the first is "lost" somehow

Comment: I hope I´m wrong but I´m afraid increasing the number of packets will only make things worse. Part of my problems were due to having two network interfaces with incorrect priorities. Please, make sure that that´s not the case (disable one of them). Also, try to have more packets with less data each in order to reduce the overhead. by doing that I fixed my problems.